# Use javascript extrapolate list of filenames and extensions from massive text file

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, substring

I have been passed a large number of text files that were created from spreadsheets. Each line of a given text file is therefore one row of a spreadsheet.

Each line contains one or more instances of an html image of the format `<img src='http://www.domainname.com/people2/images/somefilename.jpeg' alt=''width='100' style='border:none;' />`

I need to strip out everything on each line except the file names and their extensions. File extensions are not all the same types or even spellings.

Example list:

```
Some text <img src='http://www.domainname.com/people2/images/somefilename1.jpeg' alt=''width='100' style='border:none;' /> more text.
Even more text <img src='http://www.domainname.com/people2/images/somefilename2.jpg' alt=''width='100' style='border:none;' /> and so on.
Third line now, and more text <img src='http://www.domainname.com/people2/images/somefilename3.png' alt=''width='100' style='border:none;' /> with extra image <img src='http://www.domainname.com/people2/images/somefilename4.png' alt=''width='100' style='border:none;' /> and text.
```

Needs to be turned into:

```
somefilename1.jpeg
somefilename2.jpg
somefilename3.pngsomefilename4.png
```

Comment: [RegExPal](http://www.regexpal.com/) may help you

Comment: What have you tried? I'm happy to help, but I don't plan to write everything for you... That's not what SO is about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution using [***RegExp.prototype.exec()***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) function:

```js
var str =  "Some text <img src='http://www.domainname.com/people2/images/somefilename1.jpeg' alt=''width='100' style='border:none;' /> more text.\
Even more text <img src='http://www.domainname.com/people2/images/somefilename2.jpg' alt=''width='100' style='border:none;' /> and so on.\
Third line now, and more text <img src='http://www.domainname.com/people2/images/somefilename3.png' alt=''width='100' style='border:none;' /> with extra image <img src='http://www.domainname.com/people2/images/somefilename4.png' alt=''width='100' style='border:none;' /> and text.";
    var re = /<img.*?\/images\/([^'"]+).*?/gm, m,
    result = "";

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    result += ' ' + m[1];
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression, following regular expression assume that the input rows are consistent (prefixed with /images/):

```
var regex = /\/images\/([^'"]+)/g;
var results = [];
var match;
// "input" is a string from your text file.
while ((match = regex.exec(input)) !== null) {
  results.push(match[1]);
}
console.log(results);
```